# How to get Joomla Tag list in a module

Tags: joomla

I am using **Joomla 3.4.8** and it's **Article - Latest Module**. That module showed only latest article's title but I want to show introtext and tags also.
I was able to show the introtext but didn't able to show tags. Can anyone help me to figure it out? Here is my code given below.

```
<pre><code>foreach($list as $item):
echo $item->title;
echo $item->introText;
echo $item->tags->itemTag;
endforeach;</code></pre>
```

When I run this code get the error message:

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion in F:\xampp\htdocs\rnd\joomla\tx_quicx\modules\mod_articles_latest\tmpl\default.php
>   on line 37

Which corresponds to `echo $item->tags->itemTag;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's the full error message?

Comment: Hello Brandon,
Here is the error:
Notice:  Array to string conversion in F:\xampp\htdocs\rnd\joomla\tx_quicx\modules\mod_itl_portfolio\tmpl\default.php on line 37

and my line number 37 is -
echo $item->tags->itemTag;

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `tags` field is an array.

You have to reference the element number you want from that field and then reference its `itemTag`.

```
foreach($list as $item):
echo $item->title;
echo $item->introText;
echo $item->tags[0]->itemTag;
endforeach;
```

Will get the first (0th) item tag. If you want all item tags for all items, you'll have to iterate through all elements of the `tags` array.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.
Though it shows only one tag. I am trying to retrieve array elements.

Comment: Yes, the answer you posted was the code I was suggesting

Answer (score 1):

This code solve my issue.

```
foreach($list as $item){
    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->introText;
    foreach($item->tags->itemTags as $tag){
        echo $tag->title;
    }
}
```

Thanks Brandon